# ListModel.move() extremely slow

Tags: javascript, qt, sorting, qml

I have a [TableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html) with a dynamically populated [ListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) that I need to sort on the "QML-side", preferably without replacing any elements of the list as there's quite a bit of logic attached to several of the tables signals (including a few custom ones).

The problem I have is that when the table grows beyond ~1k elements, the moving of elements simply take an unreasonable long time (see code below). Putting the sorting in a WorkerScript does little to improve the UX as the users tend to just click again and again if nothing happens withing ~0.5s. So what I'm wondering is if someone knows a way to improve the performance of ListModel.move(), temporarily suppress signals, or have another solution to this?

Best Regards

Ragnar

Example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ColumnLayout {
    width: 400

    TableView {
        id: table
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        model: ListModel { dynamicRoles: false }
        onSortIndicatorColumnChanged: sort();
        onSortIndicatorOrderChanged: sort();

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "num"
            title: "Numeric column"
            width: table.contentItem.width / 3
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "str"
            title: "Text column"
            width: table.contentItem.width * 2/3
        }

        // functionality
        function sort() {
            if(model.count < 2) {
                console.log("No need to sort.");
                return true;
            }
            var r = getColumn(sortIndicatorColumn).role;
            var type = typeof(model.get(0)[r]);
            if(type != "string" && type != "number") {
                console.log("Unable to sort on selected column.");
                return false;
            }
            switch(sortMethod.currentIndex) {
                case 0: var sortFunc = _sortMoveWhileNoCache; break;
                case 1: sortFunc = _sortMoveWhile; break;
                case 2: sortFunc = _sortMoveAfter; break;
                case 3: sortFunc = _sortSetAfter; break;
                case 4: sortFunc = _sortAppendRemoveAfter; break;
                default:
                    console.log("Unknown sort method.");
                    return false;
            }
            console.time(sortFunc.name);
            sortFunc(r);
            console.timeEnd(sortFunc.name);
            return true;
        }

        // invokers
        function _sortMoveWhileNoCache(r) {
            console.time("sortMove");
            _qsortMoveNoCache(r, 0, model.count-1);
            console.timeEnd("sortMove");
        }
        function _sortMoveWhile(r) {
            console.time("setUp");
            var arr = [];
            for(var i = model.count-1; i > -1; i--) arr[i] = model.get(i)[r];
            console.timeEnd("setUp");
            console.time("sortMove");
            _qsortMove(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
            console.timeEnd("sortMove");
        }
        function _sortMoveAfter(r) {
            console.time("setUp");
            var arr = [];
            arr[0] = { "val": model.get(0)[r], "oldIdx": 0, "oldPrev": null };
            for(var i = 1; i < model.count; i++) {
                arr[i] = { "val": model.get(i)[r],
                           "oldIdx": i,
                           "oldPrev": arr[i-1] };
            }
            console.timeEnd("setUp");
            console.time("sort");
            _qsortVal(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
            console.timeEnd("sort");
            console.time("move");
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(arr[i].oldIdx !== i) {
                    model.move(arr[i].oldIdx, i, 1);
                    for(var prev = arr[i].oldPrev;
                        prev !== null && prev.oldIdx >= i;
                        prev = prev.oldPrev)
                        prev.oldIdx++;
                }
            }
            console.timeEnd("move");
        }
        function _sortSetAfter(r) {
            console.time("setUp");
            var arr = [], tmp = [];
            for(var i = model.count-1; i > -1; i--) {
                var lmnt = model.get(i);
                // shallow clone
                tmp[i] = Object.create(lmnt);
                for(var p in lmnt) tmp[i][p] = lmnt[p];
                arr[i] = { "val": tmp[i][r], "oldIdx": i };
            }
            console.timeEnd("setUp");
            console.time("sort");
            _qsortVal(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
            console.timeEnd("sort");
            console.time("set");
            // set()ing invalidates get()ed objects, hence the cloning above
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) model.set(i, tmp[arr[i].oldIdx]);
            console.timeEnd("set");
            delete(tmp);
        }
        function _sortAppendRemoveAfter(r) {
            console.time("setUp");
            var arr = [], tmp = [];
            for(var i = model.count-1; i > -1; i--) {
                tmp[i] = model.get(i);
                arr[i] = { "val": tmp[i][r], "oldIdx": i };
            }
            console.timeEnd("setUp");
            console.time("sort");
            _qsortVal(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
            console.timeEnd("sort");
            console.time("appendRemove");
            // append()ing does not, on win10 x64 mingw, invalidate
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) model.append(tmp[arr[i].oldIdx]);
            model.remove(0, arr.length);
            console.timeEnd("appendRemove");
        }

        // sorting functions
        function _qsortMoveNoCache(r, s, e) {
            var i = s, j = e, piv = model.get(Math.floor((s+e)/2))[r];
            while(i < j) {
                if(sortIndicatorOrder == Qt.AscendingOrder) {
                    for(; model.get(i)[r] < piv; i++){}
                    for(; model.get(j)[r] > piv; j--){}
                } else {
                    for(; model.get(i)[r] > piv; i++){}
                    for(; model.get(j)[r] < piv; j--){}
                }
                if(i <= j) {
                    if(i !== j) {
                        model.move(i, j, 1);
                        model.move(j-1, i, 1);
                    }
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            if(s < j) _qsortMoveNoCache(r, s, j);
            if(i < e) _qsortMoveNoCache(r, i, e);
        }
        function _qsortMove(arr, s, e) {
            var i = s, j = e, piv = arr[Math.floor((s+e)/2)];
            while(i < j) {
                if(sortIndicatorOrder == Qt.AscendingOrder) {
                    for(; arr[i] < piv; i++){}
                    for(; arr[j] > piv; j--){}
                } else {
                    for(; arr[i] > piv; i++){}
                    for(; arr[j] < piv; j--){}
                }
                if(i <= j) {
                    if(i !== j) {
                        model.move(i, j, 1);
                        model.move(j-1, i, 1);
                        var tmp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = tmp;
                    }
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            if(s < j) _qsortMove(arr, s, j);
            if(i < e) _qsortMove(arr, i, e);
        }
        function _qsortVal(arr, s, e) {
            var i = s, j = e, piv = arr[Math.floor((s+e)/2)].val;
            while(i < j) {
                if(sortIndicatorOrder == Qt.AscendingOrder) {
                    for(; arr[i].val < piv; i++){}
                    for(; arr[j].val > piv; j--){}
                } else {
                    for(; arr[i].val > piv; i++){}
                    for(; arr[j].val < piv; j--){}
                }
                if(i <= j) {
                    if(i !== j) {
                        var tmp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = tmp;
                    }
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            if(s < j) _qsortVal(arr, s, j);
            if(i < e) _qsortVal(arr, i, e);
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "Add 1000 elements (" + table.model.count + ")"
            onClicked: {
                var chars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ";
                for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    var str = "";
                    for(var j = 0; j < Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+1; j++)
                        str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length)];
                    table.model.append({ "num": Math.round(Math.random()*65536),
                                         "str": str });
                }
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Clear list model"
            onClicked: table.model.clear();
        }
        ComboBox {
            id: sortMethod
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            editable: false
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement { text: "Move while sorting, no cache" }
                ListElement { text: "Move while sorting" }
                ListElement { text: "Move after sorting" }
                ListElement { text: "Set after sorting" }
                ListElement { text: "Append and remove after sorting" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the above with Qt-win10-x64-mingw, 5k elements, clearing the list in between each sorting method I get the following results (_sortSetAfter ~20x faster than _sortMoveWhile[NoCache])

```
// num
sortMove: 3224ms
_sortMoveWhileNoCache: 3224ms
// str
sortMove: 3392ms
_sortMoveWhileNoCache: 3392ms

// num
setUp: 20ms
sortMove: 4684ms
_sortMoveWhile: 4704ms
// str
setUp: 16ms
sortMove: 3421ms
_sortMoveWhile: 3437ms

// num
setUp: 18ms
sort: 15ms
move: 4985ms
_sortMoveAfter: 5018ms
// str
setUp: 8ms
sort: 20ms
move: 5200ms
_sortMoveAfter: 5228ms

// num
setUp: 116ms
sort: 21ms
set: 27ms
_sortSetAfter: 164ms
// str
setUp: 63ms
sort: 26ms
set: 25ms
_sortSetAfter: 114ms

// num
setUp: 20ms
sort: 19ms
appendRemove: 288ms
_sortAppendRemoveAfter: 328ms
// str
setUp: 22ms
sort: 26ms
appendRemove: 320ms
_sortAppendRemoveAfter: 368ms
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are doing tons of data maipulation in JavaScript instead of in C++?

Comment: I'd suggest using a custom ListModel (maybe even in c++ if you need the performance), detach the model from your view and sort it without updating the UI and then attach the model again.. unless you want fancy sorting animations, but that costs massive performance obvioulsy. :)

Comment: And I'd suggest using this library : https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel/ . It allows you to instantiate and configure a proxy model from QML but is implemented in c++. Disclaimer : I'm its creator

Comment: The reason for doing it in Javascript is that the back-end is not in C++ but go, using [qml-go](https://github.com/limetext/qml-go) which doesn't support model-views (yet). The QML front-end is just one of several.

@xander , detaching the model does sound like a good idea, will try that (hopefully it won't fire off to many signals).

Comment: Sorry about the double comments, just realized that I didn't properly respond to the question from @KevinKrammer. As i wrote in the comment to **derM** sending data between the back- and front-end _may_ take even more (>1s) time, and I figured since the list will never contain >10k, in most cases <100, elements JS would suffice.

Comment: detaching the model as @xander suggested does increase the move()-performance by a factor of ~2.5!

Comment: @Ragnar I see, quite strange that an explicit QML binding for a language would have such a restriction, being able to do native models is essential for using a `QtQuick` GUI. It is not a matter of performance but long term viability. JavaScript code is runtime checked, one needs tests that cover ever possible path to have reliable behavior stability, while most "backend" languages have tools (compiler, static code analyzers, etc)

Comment: @KevinKrammer I should clarify, qml-go does have _some_ support for model-views (there's even an [example](https://github.com/limetext/qml-go/tree/master/examples/modelview/delegate)) it just differs in structure from the native one. To be honest, the root of the problem is not any shortcoming of qml-go but rather my design choices, making my first comment a bit misleading - sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I agree with *Kevin Krammer* and *xander*, you have multiple ways to surpress bindings.

Either you can bind them with the `signal.connect(slotToConnect)` and disconnect them with `signal.disconnect(slotToDisconnect)` directly, or you use [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html) with a `enabled`-value that you change uppon start and completion of the sorting.

Further you should consider to display some [`BusyIndicator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-busyindicator.html) when you have some actions taking longer than a few *ms*.

But I need to admit, I can't see no reason for doing this in **JS**

Comment: so you can see a reason ? (:

Comment: *negative concord*

Comment: Moving the signalhandlers to Connections does sound very promising, will give that a try. As for the JS part, as i mentioned in the comment above the QML front-end is just one of several and sending data between the back- and front-end _may_ be even more time consuming.

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourselft with the MVVM-Pattern. There you have 3 layers: The Model, the View and an intermediary model, the ViewModel. So instead of having the data been set from the (possible remote) back-end to the front-end you send it to the middel-non-end (ViewModel) which will take care of preparing it for the View, and the View finally binds to it to display the prepared (e.g. sorted data). So the ViewModel is basically a layer that takes care of almost everything you would do in JS, especially the time-consuming stuff. QML is no place for data to live in.

Comment: @derM That is the pattern I'm going for in the planned, but still pretty distant, rewrite of large chunks of the program. The problem at hand arose from ill-informed, and thus unsurprisingly bad, design choices on my part early on. It hasn't caused any _major_ headaches yet, and should this turn out to be too much of a hassle the users (which are the people i work with day to day) will simply have to deal with a `BusyIndicator` when they sort until rewrite-time :).

Answer (score 0):

It actually isn't as essential that you have a high-performance sort. Any algorithm, regardless of how good it is, if it takes more than 50ms to execute the user will notice blocking in the main QML engine thread which makes the user will feel that the application is unresponsive at times. In fact, what is actually needed is a sort algorithm that works with Qt QML by calling `Qt.callLater` after a 50ms threshold is reached so that UI/UX maintains responsiveness. To that end, we can implement a simple binary insertion incremental merge sort that moves unsorted records to their sorted location. Because of this 50ms threshold, it gives the user to interrupt and change the sort conditions.

A simple solution may look like this:

- it has sortByDOB - for sorting dates normalized as with a ms epoch
- for comparison I provide sortByName
- the main loop has `Date.now() < ts + 50` to put a 50ms threshold
- it's incremental sort and QML friendly it reacts to `count` property binding changes, so, external code can append to this `ListModel` and trigger more sorting
- there's a property binding on the `sortCompare` property so if the conditions are changed, it will reset the incremental sort
- the `ListModel` is populated with sample data which illustrates the recommended storage of Dates, i.e. the normalizing to a ms epoch
- when unsorted items become sorted, we update `sortCount`.
- we have a `bool sorted` property which indicates sorting is complete when `sortCount >= count`
- we have another `bool sorting` property which indicates sorting is ongoing when `sorted === false`

```
ListView {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    model: sortListModel
    delegate: Text { text: name }
}
ListModel {
    id: sortListModel
    property int sortCount: 0
    property var sortCompare: sortByDOB
    property var sortByName: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    property var sortByDOB: (a, b) => a.dob - b.dob
    readonly property bool sorted: sortCount >= count
    readonly property bool sorting: !sorted
    onSortCompareChanged: Qt.callLater(resort)
    onCountChanged: {
        if (count === 0) { sortCount = 0; return; }
        Qt.callLater(sortStep);
    }
    function resort() {
        sortCount = 0;
        Qt.callLater(sortStep);
    }
    function sortStep() {
        for (let ts = Date.now(); sortCount < count && Date.now() < ts + 50; ) sortItem(sortCount++);
        if (sortCount < count) Qt.callLater(sortStep);
    }
    function findInsertIndex(item, head, tail) {
        if (head >= count)  return head;
        let cmp = sortCompare(item, get(head));
        if (cmp <= 0) return head;
        cmp = sortCompare(item, get(tail));
        if (cmp === 0) return tail;
        if (cmp > 0) return tail + 1;
        while (head + 1 < tail) {
            let mid = (head + tail) >> 1;
            cmp = sortCompare(item, get(mid));
            if (cmp === 0) return mid;
            if (cmp > 0) head = mid; else tail = mid;
        }
        return tail;
    }
    function sortItem(index) {
       if (index === 0) return;
       let newIndex = findInsertIndex(get(index), 0, index - 1);
       if (newIndex === index) return;
       move(index, newIndex, 1);
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        append( { "name": "fred", dob: (new Date("1980-01-01")).getTime() } );
        append( { "name": "wilma", dob: (new Date("1985-01-01")).getTime() } );
        append( { "name": "barney", dob: (new Date("1981-01-01")).getTime() } );
        append( { "name": "betty", dob: (new Date("1983-01-01")).getTime() } );
    }
}
```

I have a more comprehensive implementation of the above solution here:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-sortlistmodel